# Measurable Function and Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I want to prove using Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality that for any positive function $f$, that $\int_E f \text{ }dm \int_E \frac {1}{f} dm \geq m(E)^2$.

Here's what I've got so far.

First, note that by CS, we have $||f||_2||g||_2 \geq ||fg||_1$. Set $g$=$1/f$, and observe that $||f||_2||\frac{1}{f}||_2 \geq||1||_1=m(E).$

Now $||f||_2 = (\int_E|f|^2dm)^{\frac {1}{2}},$ so together we have that

$(\int_E f^2dm)(  \int\frac {1}{f^2}dm) \geq m(E)^2$ by simply squaring both sides.

But now I'm feeling stuck. What I wanted to prove did not have these exponents in the integrand, and I'm not sure how to get rid of them to finish the proof. Is it some simple step I'm missing, or am I going about this the wrong way altogether?

Comment: Look at $\sqrt{f}$ instead.

Comment: Derp. Thanks. Now I feel kind of silly for asking. Measure Theory is kicking my butt this semester. I really should have seen that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** at the RHS of the Cauchy Schwarz, there are squares inside the integral. So, try with $\sqrt{|f|}$.